# Why does -1 << 23 and -1 << 55 return the same value in Java?

Tags: java, long-integer, bit-shift

Why does -1 << 23 and -1 << 55 return the same value in Java? It seems they should be very different, as I'm shifting by a lot more places! However, they result in the same value. Why does this happen?

```
public class BitShifting {
  public static void main(String... args) {
    long foo = -1 << 23;
    long bar = -1 << 55;

    System.out.println(foo);
    System.out.println(bar);
  }
}
```

Output:

```
-8388608
-8388608
```

Comment: Ah crap, missed that. Thanks @AndyBrown

Comment: Compare it with `-1L << 55` and `-1L >>> -1` for interest.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Because `1` is an `int`, not a `long`, and the conversion to `long` doesn't happen until after the assignment statement. Java will notice that the left hand argument is an `int` and not a `long`, and will round the right hand value accordingly.

[From the JLS](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.19):

> If the promoted type of the left-hand operand is int, only the five lowest-order bits of the right-hand operand are used as the shift distance. It is as if the right-hand operand were subjected to a bitwise logical AND operator `&` ([§15.22.1](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.22.1)) with the mask value `0x1f` (`0b11111`). The shift distance actually used is therefore always in the range `0` to `31`, inclusive.

The behavior will be as expected if the left hand argument is declared with `1L`, as below:

```
public class BitShifting {
  public static void main(String... args) {
    long foo = -1L << 23;
    long bar = -1L << 55;

    System.out.println(foo);
    System.out.println(bar);
  }
}
```

Output:

```
-8388608
-36028797018963968
```

Comment: Not really seeing the value in posting Yet Another Question (we have lots of them here) about not realizing that numeric literals in Java are `int`s if you already know the answer. *Yes*, asking and answering your own question is fine, but if it's very-well-covered ground, I'm not seeing the point.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder The interesting part is that the right hand operand gets masked, not that numeric literals are `int`s

Comment: I'd suggest using `1L` instead of `1l` for readability